# Two conditions using OR in XPATH

Tags: javascript, xpath, translate, uppercase, lowercase

I have a textbox, 'txtSearch'. I am using it to search people by Last Name. this is my code.

```
var xmlTempResultSearch = xmlResidentListDisplay.selectNodes(
    "//PeopleList/Row[contains(translate(@LastName, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" +
    txtSearch.value + "')]");
```

This code selects all last names in the XML like the text input in the txtSearch textbox.

This translates all uppercase letters to lowercase letters.

So if I am searching for 'Dorosan', if I type 'doro', it retrieves the correct person because it translated the 'D' to 'd'. But when I type 'Doro', it doesn't retrieve the correct person.

I'm wondering if I can have two conditions in an XPATH, and how? I want to be able to translate all uppercase to lowercase, OR translate all lowercase to uppercase.

Answer (score 61):

`and` and `or` are allowed inside the condition: `[here]`. Or you may also use multiple paths in one XPath expression using the pipe sign.

`//PeopleList/Row[c1] | //PeopleList/Row[c2]`

Comment: for Ms SQL Server using .exist("xpath") - it shows error XQuery [dvEd.EnrichmentData.exist()]: The XQuery syntax 'union' is not supported.

Answer (score 47):

you can use `or` / `and` inside `[....]`

Example:

```xml
//*[contains('abc') or contains('def') or text()='abcdef']
```

More info about operators:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need an "or" here. You just need to translate both operands to lower-case, rather than only translating one of them.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by Michael Kay, no `or` is necessary.

**Simply use**:

```
PeopleList/Row
  [contains(translate(@LastName, 
                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" 
+
           translate(txtSearch.value,
                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')'" 

+ "')]");
```