# How to select two different elements with an XPath query

Tags: php, xpath, css-selectors

I select `<a id="categoryBrandIcon">` with:

```
$item = $xpath->query("//a[@id='categoryBrandIcon']")->item(0);
```

How do I modify the code to select `<a id="categoryBrandIcon">` and all `<input type="hidden">` tags?

Selecting inputs if `input[@type='hidden']` but I don't know how to chain those two.

With CSS selectors I would do this `a#categoryBrandIcon, input[type="hidden"]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two conditions using OR in XPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could combine them in a single xpath query thru pipe. Example:

```
$sample_markup = '
<div class="container">
    <a id="categoryBrandIcon" href="#">Test</a>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="text" />
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($sample_markup);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//a[@id='categoryBrandIcon'] | //input[@type='hidden']");
foreach($elements as $e) {
    // loop thru found elements
}
```

Comment: How you would remove them withiout loop usage?

Comment: @Ultra could you kindly rephrase it? `remove them without loop usage`? how are you going to scan thru those found elements?

Comment: To access each node (and delete it for example) I need foreach loop - is there a way to access them as a group and delete them?

Comment: @Ultra like `$e->parentNode->removeChild($e)` ? i don't think there is such function that does mass delete nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two xpath queries with a vertical bar, so just chain your two queries together:

```
//a[@id='categoryBrandIcon'] | //input[@type='hidden']
```