# Multiple alternate selections

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am examining two potentially different pages for a user name (verifying text is there).  Like this:

1: 
    `<div>billgates@starbucks.com</div>`

2: 
    `<span>billgates@starbucks.com</span>`

I am using Java and selenium.  In my java function right now I have my

`method( String type, String user)` and then do

```
`if (type.equals("Vendor") ) {
   xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'USERNAME')]".replace("USERNAME", username);
} else {
    xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'USERNAME')]".replace("USERNAME", username);
}`
```

This is fine but I would like to be able to put them together, something like
`//(div OR span)[contains(text(),'USERNAME')]".replace("USERNAME", username);`

Is there a good way to do this?  And yes I can say

```
`"//div[contains(text(),'" + username + "')]"` (or span)
```

but that confuses me more opening and closing quotes.

Comment: I don't want to use "//*" because in the previous screen you enter the username in a box and this would find the //input also

Answer (score 1):

If the element you are looking for is either a `div` or `span` element, use the following expression:

```
xpath = "//*[self::div or self::span][contains(text(),'USERNAME')]".replace("USERNAME", username);
```

Comment: @user3257891 You are welcome. Let me know if it works. And please have another look at your previous questions! Some of them have [**answers that you should accept**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This is the right way, within XPath 1.0, to select "div or span". +1

Answer (score -1):

You could use operators. Check more here - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp.

```
if("//div[contains(text(),'USERNAME')]" | "//span[contains(text(),'USERNAME')]") {
    //do stuff
}
```

### Edit1

Selenium documentation on xpath, it uses browsers native xpath engine wherever possible - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath

Comment: XPath operators are operators _inside_ an XPath expression. Are you sure Selenium accepts such a syntax? (I did not downvote btw.)

Comment: @MathiasMüller not necessarily. If you check the link I provided,  it does mention this example on the first line of the table `//book | //cd`

Comment: First off, you should never trust content from w3schools.com - sometimes it's just rubbish. But in this case, read it again. It says those operators can be used **in** XPath expressions. The operands of `|` are themselves XPath expressions, but `|` is still part of the expression. In your line of code, it seems that `|` is _outside_ of any expression.

Comment: I not only read that, I also followed this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath

Comment: That's a question about XPath in Javascript - why do you expect the rules to be the same in Selenium? And you still do not understand me. I'm not saying that `|` is not an XPath operator (far from it). I am saying that `'//div' | '//span'`places `|` _outside_ of any XPath expression and I'm asking if this is allowed or understood by Selenium.

Comment: I understand your point, and I'm trying to say that if I read document correctly you could use `|` expression outside `[]`. For second point, As far as I know, JS uses browser Xpath engine and so does selenium-webdriver. only for IE webdriver injects xpath engine due to lack of it in IE.

Comment: No, until now you haven't been trying to explain that this is allowed in the Selenium documentation. If so, why not link to this documentation?

Comment: Thanks.  I don't understand the back tick (`).  Does that mean evaluate what is inside?  And is the if statement a java if or selenium if?

Comment: @MathiasMüller gotcha, I updated the answer, thanks. I added back tick because the code was looking like a comment without it and it has no significance as such.

Comment: Sorry I forgot.  You put backticks around code.  I actually did that too and I think in my example it also showed up.