# Webdriver returns NoSuchElementException for valid XPath and element is present and correct

Tags: python, html, dom, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Each of the Google review score elements (of which there are 20) on a page such as [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=chiropractors%2Bnew%20york%2Bny&rflfq=1&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2&oll=40.753684075373776,-73.98139879999997&ospn=0.009947864395265071,0.01613616943359375&oz=16&fll=40.75791015795404,-73.95807431040645&fspn=0.03978892801050904,0.064544677734375&fz=14&rlfi=hd:;si:&rlha=0):

[image]

is defined in XPath thus:

```
  //ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
```

Using Python and WebDriver, I can extract these thus (where `result` is i in range(1,21):

```
reviewCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span" % result).text
```

For some reason (which I've yet to determine), whenever review count is zero, and the text is 'No Reviews', this returns a `NoSuchElementException`. One would think that the above XPath would continue to work (indeed, viewing its XPath in Firebug proves that it follows the exact same structure as such an element with a non-zero score). So I am currently handling this with a try/catch:

```
try:
    reviewCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span" % result).text
    reviewCount = int(reviewCount.split()[0].replace(',',''))
except NoSuchElementException, e:
    reviewCount = 0
```

This is proving very costly from a time point of view in my program. Each time a *No Reviews* is encountered, the program takes several seconds to process it. In an effort to speed things up, I could try grabbing *all* review scores in one go by using find_element**S**_by_xpath. But then, how would I account for the incrementing div index? And how would I still maintain some sort of exception-handling per element?

```
//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
etc.
```

More fundamentally, why is Webdriver returning a NoSuchElementException for an element that is present and correct and only differs in its text value?

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath multiple criteria

Example:-

```
//input[@id='username' or @name='pwd']
```

Refer below thread:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath
```