# Using an OR condition in Xpath to identify the same element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this logic which gets the current page's title first clicks on next button, fetches the title again and if both the titles are the same, meaning navigation has not moved to the next page, it clicks on Next again.

However, my problem is that the title element's Xpath differs - the same title element has two Xpaths. One is some pages the other in some other pages.

It is either this,

```
(.//span[@class='g-title'])[2]
```

OR

```
.//span[@class='g-title']
```

So, how can I handle this?

Comment: whatz that index '2'. Can you post url which u r using..?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using xpath to find out the page title? Selenium Webdriver API has got a method to get the page title (like the one suggested in below answer for Java binding). Thanks.

Comment: if you are looking OR (|) operator in xpath, you can try like this "(.//span[@class='g-title'])[2]|.//span[@class='g-title']" . i hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the element has two xpath, then you can write two xpaths like below

`xpath1 | xpath2`

Eg: `//input[@name="username"] | //input[@id="wm_login-username"]`

It will choose any one xpath

Comment: What is for "And" condition?

Comment: this is nice because you can put two complete xpaths next to each other without worrying about another syntax.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **`or`**, like below:

```
//tr[@class='alternateRow' or @class='itemRow']
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `or` operator like

```
(.//span[@class='g-title'])[2] or .//span[@class='g-title']
```

For more details : [Two conditions using OR in XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath)

Answer (score 4):

I had an interesting insight I had using this method. In my python code I was clicking a cart button and the or "|" ONLY works with separate xpath statements like so ...

```
WebDriverWait(webdriver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='buttoncount-1'] | //button[contains(text(), 'Add to Cart')]")))
```

or

```
btn = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='buttoncount-1'] | //button[contains(text(), 'Add to Cart')]")
```

I found that "or" ONLY works when they share the same bracket []

```
 WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(), 'Add to Cart') or contains(text(),'Buy')]"))).click()
```

And since you're here. If you're curious about "and" statements this worked for me...

```
 WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(), 'Continue To Order Rev')][@data-attr='continueToOrderReviewBtn']"))).click()
```

Simply pairing two separate statements was sufficient. No "and" necessary.
**Note:** This was all in python. I do not know how this will transfer over to java. Hope this was somewhat useful. It took me a few migraines to narrow this down.