# How to add OR logic within an xpath expression?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

How to add `OR` logic within an xpath locator?

Is it possible to add `OR` logic within an xpath locator, so they my test scripts are using one or the other?

For example I have constructed the following locator:

```
//div[contains(@id,'va:results')]//h1 | //div[contains(@id,'va:results')]//h3
```

The test scripts seem to throw the odd exception:

```
Exception: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@id,'va:results')]//h1 | //div[contains(@id,'va:results')]//h3"}
```

But the tests are not failing; as I'm assuming one of the above selectors are being used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an OR condition in Xpath to identify the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523638/using-an-or-condition-in-xpath-to-identify-the-same-element). You can use `|`, should return existing one (h1 or h3) or both (h1 and h3)

Answer (score 0):

To add `OR` logic within an xpath expression so your test script can use one or the other you can use the following solution:

```
//div[contains(@id,'va:results')]//[@h1 or @h3]
```