# How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium in C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Seems like there's an `ExpectedCondition.Or()` method in selenium for other languages, but I could not find it in `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` for .NET

Is there any way to verify if one of two elements exist using Selenium with .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

1. Put the "OR" into your locator. An example with CSS selectors is to add a `,` in the locator. If you want to find the element with the ID `element1` or the ID `element2`, then you can use the CSS selector `#element1, #element2`. There's an OR operator in XPath if you want that also. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523638/using-an-or-condition-in-xpath-to-identify-the-same-element) as one example.
2. You can write your own custom condition that takes an array of locators (in case you want to look for more than just two).

   ```
   public Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> AnyElementExists(By[] locators)
   {
       return (driver) =>
       {
           foreach (By locator in locators)
           {
               IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> e = _driver.FindElements(locator);
               if (e.Any())
               {
                   return e.ElementAt(0);
               }
           }

           return null;
       };
   }
   ```

   and then call it like

   ```
   By[] locators = { By.Id("element1"), By.Id("element2") };
   IWebElement foundElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(AnyElementExists(locators));
   ```

   and then `foundElement` is the first element found that matches your locators. There may be more than one that matches, but this would be the first. You can alter the method to do whatever else you want or add more, etc. depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom condition

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElements(firstBy).Count > 0 || d.FindElements(secondBy).Count > 0;
});
```