# How to extract data from both th and td tags using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, list-comprehension

So I'm trying to scrape data from the DOL website for a project using selenium with python. I'm trying to scrape the column data to be combined into a data frame. The problem is that the first two columns are coded under `<th>` tags so an xpath command doesn't work when trying to extract this data. I really need help with this. I've been wracking my brain and searching everywhere, I can't find anywhere that this problem is addressed. Please help.

```
   <tr>
   <th id="Alabama" align="left">Alabama</th>
   <th id="01/04/2020" align="right">01/04/2020</th>
   <td headers="Alabama 01/04/2020 initial_claims" align="right">4,578</td>
   <td headers="Alabama 01/04/2020 reflecting_week_ended" align="right">12/28/2019</td>
   <td headers="Alabama 01/04/2020 continued_claims" align="right">18,523</td>
   <td headers="Alabama 01/04/2020 covered_employment" align="right">1,923,741</td>
   <td headers="Alabama 01/04/2020 insured_unemployment" align="right">0.96</td>
   </tr>
```

```py
   from selenium import webdriver
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
   from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   
   url = 'https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/claims.asp'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
   
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   driver.get(url)
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="level"][value="state"]').click()
   Select(driver.find_element_by_name('strtdate')).select_by_value('2020')
   Select(driver.find_element_by_name('enddate')).select_by_value('2022')
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="filetype"][value="html"]').click()
   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('states'))

   # Iterate through and select all states
   for opt in select.options:
       opt.click()
   input('Press ENTER to submit the form')
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="submit"][value="Submit"]').click()

   headers = []
   heads = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/th')

   #Collect headers
   for h in heads:
       headers.append(h.text)

   rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr')
   
   # Get row count
   row_count = len(rows) 

   cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th/td')
   # Get column count
   col_count = len(cols)
```

I've tried this code

```py
   cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th' and '//* [@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td')
```

as suggested. However, it still only pulls 5 columns, but as you can see from the HTML above, there are 7 columns. I need them all. Please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an OR condition in Xpath to identify the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523638/using-an-or-condition-in-xpath-to-identify-the-same-element)

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response. I'm going to look right now.

Comment: So I tried ```cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('[//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th] | [//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td]')```, ```cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('[//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th] or [//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td]')```, and  ```cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('[//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th]' or '[//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td]')```. These methods didn't work. Am I writing it incorrectly?

Comment: Okay, so I finally got the code to work. But it's still only reading 5 columns for some reason. But thanks for letting me know about this, because I didn't know that you could put logical statements in selenium element commands. Also, I used and, instead of or. or only picks up two columns.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Print all the headers `State`, `Filed week ended`, `Initial Claims`, `Reflecting Week Ended` or you want the table data within?

Comment: @DebanjanB, no I was able to extract the headers without a problem. I needed to grab all of the th and td tags under the actual headers to be able to create a data frame. The first two columns are table data ```<td>```, but are tagged as headers ```<th>``` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract data from all the 7 columns by using `*` or `name()` in the xpath. The xpath would be something like below.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")

cols = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./*") # Gets all the columns element within the element row. Use a Dot in the xpath to find elements within an element.
Or 
cols = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./*[name()='th' or name()='td']") # Gets all the column elements with tag name "th" or "td" within the element row.
```

Try like below:

```
# Get the rows
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")

# Iterate over the rows
for row in rows:
    # Get all the columns for each row. 
    # cols = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")
    cols = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./*[name()='th' or name()='td']")
    temp = [] # Temproary list
    for col in cols:
        temp.append(col.text)
    print(temp)
```

```
['']
['State', 'Filed week ended', 'Initial Claims', 'Reflecting Week Ended', 'Continued Claims', 'Covered Employment', 'Insured Unemployment Rate']
['Alabama', '01/04/2020', '4,578', '12/28/2019', '18,523', '1,923,741', '0.96']
['Alabama', '01/11/2020', '3,629', '01/04/2020', '21,143', '1,923,741', '1.10']
['Alabama', '01/18/2020', '2,483', '01/11/2020', '17,402', '1,923,741', '0.90']
...
```

Comment: This is the code that I tried and it's not working at all. It's not pulling any columns; ```cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[name()="th"]/table/tbody/tr[3]' or './/*[name()="td"]/table/tbody/tr[3]')``` . Can you please tell me the logic  behind using rows instead of driver? I get an error message every time I try to use rows. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Nini - As per the xpath - `//*[name()="th"]/table/tbody/tr[3]` - You are trying to find `table` element within the element with tag name `th`. its the other way. Try to find `th` which is inside the `table`.

Comment: If you observe carefully, I am iterating over the list `rows`. Using keyword `row` to do the same.  So I am trying to find all the columns inside that particular row. If we use `driver`, on each iteration it would return column elements of the first row.  Refer this link to find unique locators - [Link](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the data from both `<th>` and `<td>` tags you can use [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945168/access-to-table-objects-on-webpage-using-python-selenium/69947765#69947765) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/claims.asp")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[value='state']"))).click()
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name('strtdate')).select_by_value('2020')
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name('enddate')).select_by_value('2022')
  Select(driver.find_element_by_id('states')).select_by_visible_text('Alabama')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']").click()
  # To print all the texts from the first row
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[summary*='Report Table'] tbody tr:nth-child(3)"))).text)
  print("*****")
  # To create a List with all the texts from the first row using List Comprehension
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[summary*='Report Table'] tbody tr:nth-child(3) [align='right']")))])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Alabama 01/04/2020 4,578 12/28/2019 18,523 1,923,741 0.96
  *****
  ['01/04/2020', '4,578', '12/28/2019', '18,523', '1,923,741', '0.96']
  ```

Comment: Thank you for commenting DebanjanB, and for the links as well.

Comment: It isn't a comment really but a well researched answer :) Let me know the status

Comment: I decided to work with pmadhu's answer for now. But I actually need to do more research on both to see which one is most suitable for what I need. But thanks again for your answer. It definitely helps with expanding my understanding of these things.