# How to write contains expression - Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, contains

I have two paths :

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='"+variable+"']/td[5]/span")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='"+variable+"']/td[5]")).click();
```

How can I handle both via contains so that the first or second version will be searched - with one constancy.

Comment: If you always click the `TD`, will it work in the case that a `SPAN` child exists?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement thingie = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'" + variable + "')]/td[5]"))

if (thingie.findElements(By.tagName("span")).size() != 0) {
    thingie.findElement(By.tagName("span")).click();
} else {
    thingie.click();
}
```

Create a starting point WebElement, then check to see if the `<span>` exists. If so, click on the span version, otherwise, click the td directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipeline sign |. The pipeline sign acts as a union of the elements that are returned from each part of the expression

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'"+variable+"')]/td[5] | //tr[contains(@id,'"+variable+"')]/td[5]/span")).click();
```

The **contains** looks not necessary, the expression could be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='"+variable+"']/td[5]/span | //tr[@id='"+variable+"']/td[5]")).click();
```

Reference:
[Two conditions using OR in XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite the `xpaths` including the `contains` keyword along with a variable expression you can use the following lines of code :

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'" + variable + "')]/td[5]/span")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'" + variable + "')]/td[5]")).click()
```

Comment: You´ve updated it - but first there was only the first part as copy of his question - NM

Comment: I need one contains expression  so that the first and second version will be searched. One expression.

Comment: How can you invoke `click()` on two distinct element at the same time? What is you exact use case?

Comment: the element have 1 or 2 path. Never 1 and 2.

Comment: They are two separate elements and each element is having an unique _xpath_

Comment: If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. So volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Yes, but the page appears either in version 1 or 2. I do not know which version will be after inserting the variable, therefore I am trying to find a way that allows me to find an element regardless of whether it will be in version 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@value='<REGEX>']")).click();
```

So the REGEX for your `xPath` will be (as String):

```
"^[//tr\[@id='" + variable + "\]/td\[5\]][/span]?$"
```

So you need to paste this into  and should work.

Comment: this expression find second path?Without /span ?

Comment: Yes it does. Because `[/span]?` does mean "/span" can be there 0 or 1 time. So it´s matching both.

Comment: could you paste the path with correctly completed REGEX?