# How can I use OR statements with Playwright assert

Tags: typescript, playwright

I want to check if the text content is either `one` or `two`:

```
await expect(this.header).toHaveText('one').or('two')
```

Is there a way to make it work using Playwright?

Also can this be implemented inside a sentence like

```
await expect(this.header).toHaveText("this is "+('first').or('second')+ "sentence");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regular expression as the expected value:

```js
await expect(this.header).toHaveText(/^(one|two)$/);
```

Because `.toHaveText()` matches the entire text, it should also work without anchoring the regexp (I did not test it, I just get inspired from the [documentation of `Locator.toHaveText()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text)):

```js
await expect(this.header).toHaveText(/one|two/);
```

Comment: This is working but how do I implement it inside a sentence like await expect(this.header).toHaveText("this is " + /one|two/ + "test");

Comment: `/this is (one|two) sentence/` -- learn about regular expressions: https://www.regular-expressions.info. Use https://regex101.com to build and test regular expressions.

Comment: this worked  await expect(assetPage.bulkEditAlertMSG).toHaveText(/^(These asset items have been successfully updated.|This asset has been successfully updated.)$/);

Answer (score 0):

**OR** condition can be directly handled on Xpath level:

```
'//*[text()='one' or text()='two']'
```

> Note: This solution is not only library agnostic
> (selenium/cypress/protractor/playwright)  even
> language(java/C#/JavaScript/Python) agnostic.
>
> Basically it's an universal solution and can be used *anywhere*.

Reference: [Two conditions using OR in XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath)