# Extract text from first result retrieved from "or" Playwright locator

Tags: web-scraping, playwright

I can have one of two html structures, and I won't know which one beforehand.

Either:

```html
<p class="foo">
    hello
</p>
```

Or

```html
<p class="foo">
    <span class="bar">hello</span>
    <span class="baz">world</span>
</p>
```

I want the `"hello"` text (which is dynamic, so I can't search for that specific example).

I use the ["or" locator](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or):

```cs
await page.Locator(".foo >.bar").Or(page.Locator(".foo")).First.InnerTextAsync()
```

My expectation is that it would return `"hello"`, but it actually returns `"hello\nworld"`.

Why does it do that, and how can I fix it?

(An answer in any Playwright language is fine. Thanks.)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773473

Comment: Thanks. That's a different way to handle the "or" using an xpath. But why is the above not working?

Comment: I found this problem interesting and spent good amount of time on it.

Comment: My theory is as it's looking for matching element and traversing the dom hierarchy from top to bottom , it will always end up on ".foo" as in any case it will come first in both conditions of Or in the dom hierarchy.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Thanks. That is a fair assessment of what it's doing. Would you agree with me though that it's surprising that it works this way? I think this is a bug, or at last a failure in documenting its behaviour properly - and I'm tempted to open an issue on the repo.

Comment: Added [repo issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26361).

Comment: I beleive that the sentence from docs "Creates a locator that matches **either** of the two locators" imply that it don't work as a "regular or"-/pipe-operator where it returns if first locator matches. But like an **inclusive or**. Using `await page.locator(".foo >.bar").or(page.locator(".foo")).all()` returns 2 matches since both locators matches.

Comment: ...and it returns "hello world" first since the or-part has the highest precedence. I agree that the documentation should reflect this better.